# ¿Qué palabras tienen su origen en personajes bíblicos?

Tags: etimología, nombres-propios, religión

Estaba pensando en la palabra [*adanismo*](https://dle.rae.es/adanismo), usada con frecuencia en la política, y me puse a pensar si hay otras palabras en el castellano que vengan de personajes bíblicos.

De buenas a primeras se me ocurrió *onanismo*, por Onán. Pero, ¿existen más?

Para expresiones con origen también bíblico, consulta [¿Qué expresiones tienen su origen en personajes bíblicos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35669/1674).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buscando ["personaje bíblico"](https://iedra.es/palabras/?q=personaje%20b%C3%ADblico) en el DIRAE me encuentro con:

#### Adán

- [**adánico**](https://dle.rae.es/ad%C3%A1nico): *Perteneciente o relativo a Adán, personaje bíblico.*
- [**adanida**](https://dle.rae.es/adanida): *m. poét. Ser humano, en cuanto descendiente de Adán.*
- [**adanismo**](https://dle.rae.es/adanismo): *De Adán e -ismo.*
  *m. Hábito de comenzar una actividad cualquiera como si nadie la hubiera ejercitado anteriormente.*

#### Agar

- [**agareno, na**](https://dle.rae.es/agareno):

> 1. adj. Descendiente de Agar, personaje bíblico, esclava de Abraham. U. t. c. s.
>
> 2. adj. musulmán. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.

#### Benjamín

- **[benjamín, na](https://dle.rae.es/benjam%C3%ADn)**:

> 1. adj. 1. m. y f. Hijo menor de una familia.
>
> 2. m. y f. Miembro más joven de un grupo.

#### Herodes

- [*herodes*](https://dle.rae.es/herodes): *m. Hombre cruel con los niños.*

#### Moisés

- [**mosaico, ca**](https://dle.rae.es/mosaico)<sup>1</sup>: *Del gr. Μωσαϊκός Mōsaïkós.*
  *1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a Moisés, personaje bíblico.*
  *2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al judaísmo o religión que sigue la ley de Moisés. Ceremonias mosaicas.*

#### Onán

- [**onanismo**](https://dle.rae.es/onanismo): *Del fr. onanisme, y este de Onan 'Onán', personaje bíblico, e -isme '-ismo'.*
  *m. masturbación.*

#### Salomón

- **[salomónico](https://dle.rae.es/salom%C3%B3nico)**: Dicho de una solución, de una decisión, de una sentencia, etc.: Que intenta satisfacer parcialmente a todas las partes en conflicto, con propósito de ecuanimidad.

#### Simón Cirineo

- [**cirineo**](https://dle.rae.es/cirineo): *De cireneo; en acep. 2, por alus. a Simón Cirineo, que ayudó a Jesús a llevar la cruz en el camino del Calvario.*
  *2. m. coloq. Persona que ayuda a otra en algún trabajo penoso.*

---

El DIRAE también hace referencia a las siguientes palabras, que el DLE no tiene: [*aaronita*](https://iedra.es/palabras/aaronita), [*aarónico*](https://iedra.es/palabras/aar%C3%B3nico), [*Job*](https://iedra.es/palabras/Job) así como locuciones, nombres compuestos o expresiones como [*las de Caín*](https://dle.rae.es/Ca%C3%ADn), [*arca de Noé*](https://dle.rae.es/No%C3%A9), [*andar, o ir, de Herodes a Pilatos*](https://dle.rae.es/herodes).

Comment: Añado otra _expresión_ que tienen su origen en la Biblia o personajes de la misma: "Tener más paciencia que el santo Job".  De hecho hasta aparece como ejemplo en la entrada de "[de](https://dle.rae.es/de?m=form)" del DLE. El enlace que pones del DIRAE dice que Job es un "Hombre de mucha paciencia", pero yo he oído siempre la otra expresión y nunca referirse a alguien como un "job" o decir que alguien tiene "lágrimas de Job".

Comment: @Diego cierto! También a mí me sorprendió que existiera la entrada _Job_ a secas, pues solamente he escuchado la que comentas. ¿Crees que las expresiones las podemos meter también aquí o habrá tantas que mejor en otra pregunta?

Comment: Yo las metería en otra pregunta, que podríamos hacer desde el principio community wiki. No por la cantidad sino porque me parece que es mejor limitar el contexto una pregunta a _palabras_/nombres propios de personajes bíblicos y otra a _expresiones_, que será más general (referencias a Sodoma y Gomorra, a "llevar una /ser su cruz", venderse por 30 monedas de plata, etc.).

Comment: @Diego De hecho la idea es que esta pregunta también fuera CW de inicio y así lo indiqué en un comentario inicial (que borré esta mañana, cuando la convertí en CW finalmente... debí haberlo hecho desde el principio, como bien dices). Luego han surgido otras respuestas, que si sus autores me permiten incluiré en esta respuesta general. Perfecto lo de la pregunta con expresiones, si no se ha preguntado antes lo haré durante la semana.

Comment: No sé si *mesianismo* se podría añadir a esta lista, porque el Mesías es más un concepto que un personaje. Aunque en el Nuevo Testamento se dice claramente que el Mesías es Cristo, claro.

Answer (score 6):

Además de los ya mencionados, encuentro estos:

Aarón: aarónico, aaronita.
Ismael: ismailita.
Caín: cainita.
Cam: camita.
Agar: agareno.
Amalek: amalecita, amalequita.
Amón: amonita.
Amorreo: amorreo.
Aram: arameo.
Efraín: efraimita.
Israel: israelí, israelita.
Judá: judío.
Judas: judas.
Leviatán: leviatán.
Leví: levita.
Madián: madianita.
Matusalén: matusalén.
Sem: semita.

Comment: caramba, sí que hay! Para unificar, podríamos ponerlo todo en la misma respuesta y así que una única lista. Más fácil de leer y mantener

Answer (score 5):

Y otras más:
[moisés](https://dle.rae.es/mois%C3%A9s):

> 1. m. Cestillo ligero de mimbre, lona u otra materia, con asas, que sirve de cuna portátil.

[mariano](https://dle.rae.es/mariano):

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la Virgen María o a su culto.

[marial](https://dle.rae.es/marial):

> 1. adj. p. us. Perteneciente o relativo a la Virgen María.
> 2. adj. p. us. Dicho de un libro: Que contiene alabanzas de la Virgen María. U. t. c. s. m.

[jeremías](https://dle.rae.es/jerem%C3%ADas):

> De *Jeremías*, profeta hebreo del siglo VII a. C., por alus. a sus célebres trenos o lamentaciones.
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona que continuamente se está lamentando.

[jeremiaco](https://dle.rae.es/jeremiaco) y [jeremíaco](https://dle.rae.es/jerem%C3%ADaco):

> De *Jeremías*, profeta hebreo del siglo VII a. C., por alus. a sus célebres trenos o lamentaciones.
>
> 1. adj. Que gime o se lamenta con exceso. U. t. c. s.
>
> 2. adj. Propio del profeta Jeremías o de la persona jeremíaca.

[salomón](https://dle.rae.es/salom%C3%B3n):

> Por alus. a *Salomón*, 970-931 a. C., rey de Israel y de Judá, hijo de David.
>
> 1. m. Hombre de gran sabiduría.

[jacobeo](https://dle.rae.es/jacobeo):

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al apóstol Santiago.

Por insuficiente reputación se quedan sin enlace otras, como

**sansón**

> Por alus. a Sansón, juez de Israel, dotado de fuerzas maravillosas.
>
> 1. m. Hombre muy forzudo.

**satán**

> De *Satán*, príncipe de los demonios en la tradición judeocristiana.
>
> 1. m. Persona diabólica. *Es un satán.*

**satánico, ca**

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a Satanás, príncipe de los ángeles rebelados.
> 2. adj. Propio y característico de Satanás.
> 3. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al satanismo.

**satanismo**

> 1. m. Culto a Satanás.
>
> 2. m. Perversidad, maldad satánica.

Answer (score 4):

[Jesusear](https://dle.rae.es/jesusear?):

> 1. intr. coloq. Repetir muchas veces el nombre de Jesús.

[Marta](https://dle.rae.es/marta#OUnlCMF):

> De *Marta*, hermana de María y Lázaro, quien, según los Evangelios, cuando Jesús se hospedó en su casa, preparaba solícitamente la comida, mientras su hermana María conversaba con Jesús.
> 1. f. Mujer piadosa y a la vez atenta al trabajo de casa.
>
> 2. f. Mujer aprovechada.

[Magdalena](https://dle.rae.es/magdalena?):

> De *María Magdalena*, personaje de los Evangelios.
>
> 1. f. Mujer penitente o visiblemente arrepentida de sus pecados.

y las expresiones

> **estar alguien hecho una Magdalena**, o **llorar como una Magdalena**
>
> 1. locs. verbs. Llorar mucho o desconsoladamente.
>
> **no estar la Magdalena para tafetanes**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. no estar el horno para bollos.

y, por supuesto, [Cristo](https://dle.rae.es/cristo?):

> 3. m. crucifijo.
> 4. m. coloq. Lío o alboroto.

y las expresiones

> todo cristo
> un cristo
> como a un cristo dos pistolas
> Cristo con todos
> donde Cristo dio las tres voces
> ni Cristo que lo fundó
> ni por un cristo
> sacar el cristo
> voto a Cristo

y [eccehomo](https://dle.rae.es/eccehomo?):

> 1. m. Imagen de Jesucristo como lo presentó Pilatos al pueblo.
> 2. m. Persona lacerada, rota, de lastimoso aspecto.

[Lázaro](https://dle.rae.es/l%C3%A1zaro?):

> De *Lázaro*, el mendigo de la parábola del Evangelio de san Lucas, XVI.
>
> 2. m. Pobre andrajoso.

Answer (score 4):

Aporto otra contribución:

> **[barrabasada](https://dle.rae.es/barrabasada?m=form)** (De barrabás.)

> 1. f. coloq. Desaguisado, disparate, acción que produce gran daño o perjuicio.

La palabra "barrabasada" viene por supuesto de [Barrabás](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrab%C3%A1s)<sup>1</sup>, un personaje bíblico al que se tiene por ser un hombre malvado.

> **[barrabás](https://dle.rae.es/barrab%C3%A1s?m=form)** (Por alus. a Barrabás, judío indultado con preferencia a Jesús.)

> 1. m. coloq. Persona mala, traviesa, díscola.

El nombre propio ha evolucionado a este otro sustantivo que significa "hacerle algo muy malo a alguien". Las expresiones "ser un Barrabás" o "ser más malo que Barrabás" derivan también de este personaje.

---

1- Barrabás es un personaje citado en el Nuevo Testamento, concretamente en relación con el proceso de Jesús ante Poncio Pilato. Según Marcos y Lucas, estaba encarcelado por haber participado en un motín en el que se había cometido un homicidio (Mc 15:7; Lc 23:19); Juan indica que era un bandolero (Jn 18:40); y Mateo, se refiere a él sencillamente como “un preso famoso” (Mt 27:1).

Answer (score 3):

[Deípara](https://dle.rae.es/de%C3%ADpara?):
2. f. por antonom. La Virgen María.

[Mariología](https://dle.rae.es/mariolog%C3%ADa?):
1. f. *Rel*. Parte de la teología que estudia lo referente a la Virgen María.

[Simpecado](https://dle.rae.es/simpecado?):
De *sin pecado [concebida]*, fórmula religiosa referente a la inmaculada concepción de la Virgen María.

1. m. Insignia que en las procesiones andaluzas marcha delante de las cofradías de la Virgen, y que ostenta el lema *sine labe concepta*.

[Anunciación](https://dle.rae.es/anunciaci%C3%B3n?):
2. f. por antonom. En el catolicismo, anuncio que el arcángel san Gabriel hizo a la Virgen del misterio de la encarnación.

3. f. En el catolicismo, fiesta con que la Iglesia conmemora la anunciación del arcángel a la Virgen.

[Salutación](https://dle.rae.es/salutaci%C3%B3n?):
2. f. *Rel*. Parte del sermón en la cual se saluda a la Virgen.

[Madona](https://dle.rae.es/madona?):
1. f. La Virgen María.

2. f. *Esc. y Pint*. Cuadro o imagen que representa a la Virgen María, sola o con el Niño Jesús.

[Avemaría](https://dle.rae.es/avemar%C3%ADa?):
1. f. Oración compuesta de las palabras con que el arcángel san Gabriel saludó a la Virgen María, de las que dijo santa Isabel y de otras que añadió la Iglesia católica.

2. f. Cada una de las cuentas pequeñas del rosario.

[Crucifijo](https://dle.rae.es/crucifijo?):
1. m. Efigie o imagen de Cristo crucificado.

[Crismón](https://dle.rae.es/crism%C3%B3n?):
Del lat. mediev. *chrismon*, y este acrón. de lat. *Chris*ti *mon*ogramma 'monograma de Cristo'.
1. m. *Rel*. lábaro (‖ monograma de Cristo).

Answer (score 2):

Una más: "jeremiada", de Jeremías. "Lamentación o muestra exagerada de dolor".

Answer (score 2):

[adán](https://dle.rae.es/ad%C3%A1n?):

> De *Adán*, personaje bíblico.
>
> 1. m. coloq. Hombre desaliñado, sucio o descuidado.

[Jesús](https://dle.rae.es/Jes%C3%BAs?):

> Del lat. tardío *Iesus*, y este del hebr. *yĕhošūa‘*.
>
> 1. interj. U. para expresar admiración, sorpresa o indignación. *¡Jesús, vaya modales!*
> 2. interj. U. cuando alguien estornuda.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque **cainita** está recogida en otra respuesta, veo que no lo está
[**cainismo**](https://dle.rae.es/cainismo?):

> De *Caín*, el primer fratricida, según la Biblia, e -*ismo*.
>
> 1. m. Actitud de odio o fuerte animadversión contra allegados o afines.

Answer (score 1):

si mariano es una opción válida (que pertenece al culto de María) y parece que sí porque la respuesta está votada:

[Cristiano](https://dle.rae.es/cristiano) : (por Cristo)

> Perteneciente o relativo a la religión de Cristo.

[Judeocristiano](https://dle.rae.es/judeocristiano) (por Cristo)

> Perteneciente o relativo al cristianismo en cuanto que posee raíces
> judías.

[Marista](https://www.google.com/search?ei=ATPmX6u9Ff2p5OUPu-SIgAk&q=marista%20significado&oq=marista%20significado&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIHCAAQRhD5ATIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABBHOgQIABBDOggIABDHARCvAToCCABQuAJY9QpgtQxoAHACeAKAAZ0CiAHADpIBBTEuOS4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjrwZ3-5OntAhX9FLkGHTsyApAQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) (por María)

> Que pertenece a esta congregación de Hermanitos de María.

[Abrahámico](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/abrah%C3%A1mico) (por Abraham)

> Que pertenece o concierne al patriarca Abraham (como religiones
> abrahamicas (judaísmo, cristianismo, Islam, etc.))

[Jesuita](https://www.google.com/search?ei=VjbmX6XjCMXN5OUP65-CKA&q=jesuita%20significado&oq=jesuita%20significado&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIHCAAQRhD5ATIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoICCEQFhAdEB46BwguEEMQkwI6BAgAEEM6BAguEEM6BwgAELEDEEM6BQgAELEDOgoIABCxAxCDARBDOgUILhCxAzoCCAA6CAguELEDEIMBOggIABCxAxCDAToHCC4QsQMQQzoCCC5Qz-0BWJOHAmDNiAJoAXAAeACAAcQBiAGnEpIBBTEwLjExmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwil5u-U6OntAhXFJrkGHeuPAAUQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) (por Jesús)

> Que pertenece a la Compañía de Jesús, orden fundada por san Ignacio de
> Loyola (1494-1556).

Answer (score 1):

Añado otra palabra a la larga lista (a ojo, entre todas las respuestas ya hay más de 50):

> [**GOLIARDO**](https://dle.rae.es/goliardo?):
>
> 1. adj. Dado a la gula y a la vida desordenada; seguidor del vicio y del demonio personificado en el **gigante bíblico Goliat**.

Comment: Sobre lo que comentas, históricamente en Spanish.SE hemos ido migrando hacia aceptar estas preguntas. Fíjate que publiqué una respuesta wiki para que allí estuviera el compendio, pero por algún motivo la gente prefirió meter una respuesta nueva cada vez (cosa que no comparto).

Answer (score 0):

También [pasito](https://dle.rae.es/pasito?):

> 1. m. *C. Rica*. Conjunto de figuras esculpidas de Jesús, la Virgen, san José, la mula y el buey.

Comment: No veo un origen de pasito en un personaje biblico. Puedes dar una explicacion mas larga?

Answer (score 0):

Otra palabra más:
[**preadamita**](https://dle.rae.es/preadamita?):

> 1. m. Supuesto antecesor de Adán.

Answer (score 0):

¿Sería válida [inconsútil](https://dle.rae.es/incons%C3%BAtil)?

> 1. adj. Dicho comúnmente de la túnica de Jesucristo: Sin costura.