# ¿Qué expresiones tienen su origen en personajes bíblicos?

Tags: expresiones, nombres-propios, locuciones, religión

A raíz de la pregunta [¿Qué palabras tienen su origen en personajes bíblicos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35658/1674) han surgido distintas expresiones cuyo origen también está en nombres bíblicos.

Así pues, ¿qué expresiones, locuciones y similares del castellano tienen su origen en personajes bíblicos?

Sugiero recogerlas en una única respuesta compartida (wiki) donde ordenemos por *personaje*.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>A continuación detallo las que me salen así de memoria. Es una publicación *wiki*, por lo que siéntete libre de editar para añadir, mejorar, reformatear y asi tendremos una lista más o menos exhaustiva y única. ¡Gracias!</sub>

#### Adán

- **Ser/estar hecho un Adán**: *Tener aspecto desastrado y desaliñado.*

#### Baltasar

- **Darse el festín de Baltasar**

#### Caín

- [**Las de Caín**](https://dle.rae.es/Ca%C3%ADn): *coloq. Intenciones aviesas*
- [**Pasar las de Caín**](https://dle.rae.es/Ca%C3%ADn): *loc. verb. coloq. Sufrir grandes apuros y contratiempos.*

#### Gestas

- **Más ladrón que Gestas**

#### Jesucristo

- **Cargar con la cruz**
- **Por los clavos de Cristo**
- **Estar hecho un Cristo:** Estar apaleado, herido, dolorido, hecho polvo...
- **Ir donde Cristo dio las tres voces:** Expresión para referirse a lugares muy lejanos

#### Job

- **Tener más paciencia que Job**

#### Judas

- **El beso de Judas**
- **Ser más falso que Judas/ser un Judas**

#### Herodes

- [**andar, o ir, de Herodes a Pilatos**](https://dle.rae.es/herodes): *1. locs. verbs. coloqs. Ir de una persona a otra.*
  *2. locs. verbs. coloqs. Ir de mal en peor en un asunto.*

#### María Magdalena

- **Llorar/estar como una Magdalena**

#### Pilatos

- **andar, o ir, de Herodes a Pilatos** (véase Herodes)

#### San Pedro

- **A quien Dios se la dé, San Pedro se la bendiga**: Desear que una circunstancia fortuita no suponga mayores inconvenientes.

#### Tomás

- **Ser como santo Tomás**